# Getting strange typescript errors when trying to build a turborepo project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, turborepo

I am working on a [turborepo-template](https://github.com/mayank1513/turborepo-template/). Things were working very well but suddenly TypeScript started throwing strange errors.

```bash
../../packages/fork-me/src/client/star-me/star-me.tsx:19:4
nextjs-example:build: Type error: Type 'string | number | true | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | Iterable<ReactNode>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
nextjs-example:build:   Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
nextjs-example:build:     Property 'children' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.
nextjs-example:build:
nextjs-example:build:   17 |    return (
nextjs-example:build:   18 |            <button data-testid="star-me-h1" onClick={starMe} type="button" {...props}>
nextjs-example:build: > 19 |                    {children || "Star Me"}
nextjs-example:build:      |                    ^
nextjs-example:build:   20 |            </button>
nextjs-example:build:   21 |    );
nextjs-example:build:   22 | }
```

The error is pointing to [this](https://github.com/mayank1513/turborepo-template/blob/main/packages/fork-me/src/client/star-me/star-me.tsx) file. It's really strange. The package builds without any errors, but when I am trying to build the example, it throws this strange errors.

Answer (score 0):

After a huge frustration, it turns out that the problem is fixed mystically after I deleted all node_modules, .next, .turbo, etc. And re-install the deps and build the project again.